# Adding and subtract inbetween row inputs and value equal to the first column next row using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time

Assume I have a dataset with three inputs:

```
   x1   x2  x3  
0  a    b   c
1  d    e   f
2  g    h   i
3  j    k   l
4  m    n   o
5  p    q   r
6  s    t   u 
      :
      :
```

0,1,2,3 are times, x1, x2, x3 are inputs that are measured. So here x1 inputs are measured at every one hour. x2 and x3 will be measured at different time. What I need to do , I want write that what ever the measured in x1, x2, x3 it will add and subtract the values are equal to the x1 input next time value 
So here what I want to do is:

```
    x1   x2   x3   y
 0  a    b    c   a+b-c=d
 1  d    e    f   d+e-f=g
 2  g    h    i   g+h-i=j
 3  j    k    l   j+k-l=m
 4  m    n    o   m+n-o=p
 5  p    q    r   p+q-r=s
 6  s    t    u   s+t-u=v
         :
         :
```

Here with my actual data according to my csv file:

```
             X1     x2    x3    y
   0         63      0     0    63+0-0=63
   60(min)   63      0     2    63+0-2 =104
   120       104     11    0    104+11-0=93
   180       93      0    50    93+0-50=177
   240       177     0     2    177+0-2=133
   300       133     0     0    133+0-0=next value of x1
```

I tried shift method and it didn't work for me what I want exactly. I tried another method and it worked, but didn't came as I want. Here I upload the code.

```
Code :
 data = pd.read_csv('data6.csv')
 i=0
 j=1
 while j < len(data):
   j=data['x1'][i] - data['x2'][i] + data['x3'][i] 
   i+=1 
   j!=i 
  print(j)
```

This is works , but it is just showing only one data

> 63

In my csv file this is second input value of x1 input.
I want to write this code contonously happened and read the value as I shown above.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

[My csv file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WWq1qhqi4bGzNir_svQV7VstBkGbocToipPCY83Cclc/edit#gid=1512153575)

Comment: the row with index 1 has `d+e+f!=g`, should it be `d+e-f!=g`? if not, could you please explain why the second `+`?

Comment: also, I think you should edit your example to include real data, or at least similar (in type) to your real data

Comment: @Adam.Er8  sorry I corrected it. It is d+e-f !=g. I will edit with my csv data. Give me some time.

Comment: @Adam.Er8I edited my question. Now you can check again. Thank you

Comment: Alright, seems like you do need string concatenation, look at U10-Forward's answer, it should work. just 1 question, `63+0-0!=63` is obviously not  true, are you sure you need `!=` on all rows? without ever depending on the value?

Comment: @Adam.Er8 Actually what I want is  first row value addition and subtraction will be equal to the next row value of x1. What ever value is there it will be equal to this mathematics , This is what I am trying to do.

Comment: @team you just want `df['Y']=(df[['X1','x2']].sum(1)-df.x3).ne(df.X1.shift(-1))` IIUC

Comment: @Adam.Er8 Here I applied the U10 Forward answer it gave me an error "ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')"

Comment: @anky_91 Your code is correct but it is showing true or false. I want to display the numerical value for Y , then what I have to change in your code

Comment: @team what is the numerical value you expect? i mean when you compare you get either true or false, what should be for true and what should be for false

Comment: @anky_91 I want to show the value of x1 . Assume now I wrote the mathematical equation for inputs(add and subtract)  take first row input (63+0-0 ) the value of next x1 is 63 . so print 63 . like that I want to write it.

Comment: @team unfortunately its not clear. "Assume now I wrote the mathematical equation for inputs(add and subtract) take first row input (63+0-0 )" the next value is the first value of 2nd row. why not just do`df['Y']=df['x1'].shift(-1)` then

Comment: @anky_91 Actually I want to develop the neural network model (lstm) to predict the future x1 value. For that I want to write this mathematical equation to predict the value. Because to predict the next value this mathematical equation is affect. That's why I want to write this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this with your help. Thank you very much for helping me. @Adam.Er8 , @U10-Forward and @anky_91

Here is my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)     
df['y'] = 0 
for i in range(len(df)-1): #iterating between all the rows of dataframe
   df['y'].iloc[i] == df['x1'].iloc[i] + df['x2'].iloc[i] - df['x3'].iloc[i]
   df['y'].iloc[i] = df['x1'].iloc[i+1]
```

Comment: @Adam.Er8  Thank you for helping me to solve my code. I hope this code is correct according to your comments, and this works properly with my data

Comment: , @U10-Forward Thank you for helping me to solve my code. I hope this code is correct according to your comments, and this works properly with my data

Comment: @ anky_91 Thank you for helping me to solve my code. I hope this code is correct according to your comments, and this works properly with my data

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
>>> df['y'] = df['x1'] + '+' + df['x2'] + '-' + df['x3'] + '!=' + df.shift(-1)['x1']
>>> df
  x1 x2 x3         y
0  a  b  c  a+b-c!=d
1  d  e  f  d+e-f!=g
2  g  h  i  g+h-i!=j
3  j  k  l  j+k-l!=m
4  m  n  o  m+n-o!=p
5  p  q  r  p+q-r!=s
6  s  t  u       NaN
>>>
```

Comment: note: the real data is numerical, and from the question it seems  he needs actual arithmetic computation and not just a string concatenation

Comment: (either way, what's important here the correct usage of the shift, from there its pretty easy to do whatever OP needs).

Comment: @U10-Forward  Thank you for the fast reply  and here  I agree with him ( Adam.Er8). This is just to understand I wrote. actually I want to apply the code for numerical data.

Comment: @U 10-Forward Here I edited my question again, I hope now you can understand what I mentioned

Comment: @U10-Forward Here I applied your code and it gave this error "ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')"